# List fragment is not responding in custom layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a multiple fragment layouts in Android and I have used List Fragment. I do not want to use default Array Adapter and when I am using custom Array Adapter, list view is not responding. It is unable to open another activity or fragment(in case of landscape orientation).

Here is my code and it is also present in Android official site.

TitlesFragment:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {

    boolean mDuelPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                new SuperHeroInfo();



        Fragment_Adapter connectArrayToListView=new Fragment_Adapter(getActivity(),SuperHeroInfo.NAMES);


        setListAdapter(connectArrayToListView);

        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);


        mDuelPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        // If the screen is rotated onSaveInstanceState() below will store the // hero most recently selected. Get the value attached to curChoice and // store it in mCurCheckPosition
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDuelPane) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    // When a list item is clicked we want to change the hero info
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetails(position);
    }


    void showDetails(int index) {

        // The most recently selected hero in the ListView is sent
        mCurCheckPosition = index;


        if (mDuelPane) {
            //try
            getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);


            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);


            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {

                // Make the details fragment and give it the currently selected hero index
                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                // Start Fragment transactions
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace any other Fragment with our new Details Fragment with the right data
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);

                // TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE calls for the Fragment to fade away
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }

        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent();


            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);

            // Pass along the currently selected index assigned to the keyword index
            intent.putExtra("index", index);

            // Call for the Activity to open
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment_Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Fragment_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> SmallArray;

    public Fragment_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view, objects);
        this.context=context;
        SmallArray=objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.small_text);
        text.setText(SmallArray.get(position));
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the first line in the getView method.

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getAplicationContext.getLayoutInflater();
```